# Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, arduino-uno

I am trying to connect a HC-05 Bluetooth Module (connected to Arduino Uno) to my Raspberry Pi 3 in the hopes of achieving bluetooth communication between the two to send data from the Uno to the Pi.

Trying to use Bluetoothctl to pair, connect and trust the HC-05 device seems to fail for me.

```
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 LegacyPairing: yes
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 RSSI: -43

[bluetooth]# pair 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
Attempting to pair with 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Connected: yes
Request PIN code
[agent] Enter PIN code: 1234
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Connected: no

[bluetooth]# connect 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
Attempting to connect to 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Connected: no

[bluetooth]# trust 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
[CHG] Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 Trusted: yes
Changing 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1 trust succeeded
```

Here is the info prompt.

```
[bluetooth]# info 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
Device 98:D3:31:FB:6F:F1
        Name: HC-05
        Alias: HC-05
        Class: 0x001f00
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: no
        LegacyPairing: yes
        UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

Specifically the error I am getting is "**Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable**"

I am not sure how to get pass this error and I am unable to complete my project without confirming a linked bluetooth signal between the two microprocessors.

Thanks,
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

I have Linux Mint 2020. I faced with the same Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists message.

Solution:

1. Uninstall the basic bluetooth (bluez) software in linux, then reboot
2. Install 'blueman-applet', then voila

https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-bluetooth-in-linux/

It solved my BT sound system issue.

Kind regards,
Balázs